# How to solve the error : "Could not save product "20072" with position 0 to category 7" in magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, adminhtml, magento2.2.2, save

While unasign the product from multiple categories to single category and trying to save the product, it thorow the error like below

> Could not save product "20072" with position 0 to category 7

I am saving the product mannually via admin end

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will the check then i will put tick mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed in Magento latest version.

You can check fixes [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/97d5dcc7fbea21a870a17062e0d1e7d2ca1515ea).

Comment: I am using magento 2.2.2

Comment: In which version it was fixed

Comment: it fixed in 2.2.4 @Sri

Comment: hi @NikunjVadariya, I am using 2.2.4, but still error is there,

Comment: Magento 2.2.6 still happens

Comment: I'm on 2.3.6 and error still exists...

Answer (score 5):

To fix this issue i created a custom module.

> https://github.com/khasru/magento2UrlRewritebug

Hope it helps.

Comment: after install extension. error show: Fatal error: Declaration of Scriptlodge\UrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage::doReplace(array $urls) must be compatible with Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage::doReplace(array $urls) . how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function deleteByIds($categoryId, $sku)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    $productPositions = $category->getProductsPosition();

    $productID = $product->getId();
    if (!isset($productPositions[$productID])) {
        throw new InputException(__('Category does not contain specified product'));
    }
    $backupPosition = $productPositions[$productID];
    unset($productPositions[$productID]);

    $category->setPostedProducts($productPositions);
    try {
        $category->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __(
                'Could not save product "%product" with position %position to category %category',
                [
                    "product" => $product->getId(),
                    "position" => $backupPosition,
                    "category" => $category->getId()
                ]
            ),
            $e
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

the "`echo $e->getMessage();`"  gives you the exact error. 
In my case it was "Duplication of URL key."

So just check what error message you are getting from here....

*File: Vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkRepository.php*